# systemd has a <sleep infinity > process. What is it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, sleep

I was looking through the process table and this process, `/bin/sleep infinity`, was there. It's started by `/lib/systemd/systemd --user`.

If I kill the `sleep`, my current session is stopped and I get booted off the system.

What is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: How did you log on to this session? `sleep` is a common practice to keep containerized applications running; are you working in a container environment?

Comment: I doubt it was "started by /lib/systemd/systemd --user". That process is probably the "reaper" process for your systemd user session, so any process in that session whose parent dies becomes a child of it.

Comment: No the ppid is systemd --user. How is sleep meant to keep containerized applications running? Or do you mean it is meant as a keep-alive mechanism for a containerized process? Be that as it may, kill the sleep process kills the X session, which is a little strange.

Comment: @placidchat ppid being systemd --user doesn't mean that process created it.

Comment: yes you are right. But why is this sleep process started though. It is </usr/bin/sleep infinity>. If anyone is using systemd, this should also appear.

Comment: What i mean is, anyone using systemd, ps -ef, and tell me what this is for?

Comment: @placidchat Not that easy, it seems. My Arch Linux uses systemd, but there is no `sleep` process running. I agree with the other commenters: it is unlikely to depend on systemd. For instance, on my system, the desktop environment's (KDE) application launcher runs as a child process of the user's systemd instance; if it starts a program that runs `sleep infinity &`, the `sleep` process gets reaped by the user's systemd instance, as it apparently happens in your case. I have no idea about the relation with X, though.

Comment: My distro is currently ubuntu using xfce. I was thinking there would be more people that would notice this sleep process.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick grep through /usr/lib/systemd/user and it turns out there's a service called session-monitor.service with an execstart of /bin/sleep infinity. In the description it says that this:

> Stops autojack which starts Studio audio in the same way the session
> ended as well as providing a back end for studio-controls for
> changing various settings.

which seems strange since sleep doesn't do anything except sleep. The execStopPost of session-monitor.service is `ExecStopPost=/bin/systemctl --user start systemd-exit.service`, which explains why killing this process gets the user kicked off the system.